# How can i show my articles of database in website module?

Tags: python, web, odoo, erp, odoo-10

Im working with Odoo 10, i have a big a lot of articles classified by category, and i had installed website module, now i wante to show my articles and categories in one of pages of my website

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question - and therefore the probability of getting an answer!

Answer (score 2):

To build a Website page, you can read the documentation here [https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/website.html][1]

To resume what you must doing.

The first step is creations of a link with a controller. Like this

```
from odoo import http

class Product(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/products/', auth='public')
    def index(self, **kw):
        product_ids = self.env['product.product'].search([])
        return http.request.render('academy.index', {
            'products': product_ids,
        })
```

Seconde step is creations of your template view. Like this

```
<template id="index">
    <title>Products</title>
    <t t-foreach="products" t-as="product">
      <p><t t-esc="product.name"/></p>
    </t>
</template>
```

It's a simple example. If you want more information you can read the documentation and see example in the code of odoo .

Comment: So, there s no way to build website in graphic mode ?

Comment: Sorry but I personally never using the e-comerce builder of odoo. But I have found a little video to help you . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewiPcd0gJmg

Comment: Right , i had not installed eCommerce modul , now its work , thak you so mutch

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's important to close the question ^^.

Comment: How can i do it ??